# Mountable filesystem that automatically splits files

Tags: linux, filesystems

Is there a [virtual-]filesystem that can automatically split files in storage but present them to the user as single files?

For example:

```
The user sees: /user/files/10TBfile
But it is stored as: /backingstorage/user/files/10TBfile.{1..100}
```

Basically the same way a split archive works but in real time.
I feel like it should be possible since it's basically storing each virtual disk block as a separate file but I don't know of any existing solutions for it.

If you're curious, the end goal might be something similar to this question: [Divide out local files in different servers with limited space with rsync](https://superuser.com/questions/403912/rsync-divide-out-local-files-in-different-servers-with-limited-space) except that I have single large files that need to be split and the files need to be updated in real-time so a daily cron/rsync and split tar are out of the question.  I already have the remote drives mounted so I just need a way to split the file and present it as a single file to the user.

Thanks!

Comment: Your best bet is probably to write your own using [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Have considered it, just wondering if any existing solutions exist before I go roll my own

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is [`chunkfs`](http://chunkfs.florz.de/):

> ChunkFS is a FUSE based filesystem that allows you to mount an arbitrary file or block device as a directory tree of files that each represent a chunk of user-specified size of the mounted file.

It was written for the same purpose as yours:

> ChunkFS was originally written for making space-efficient incremental backups of encrypted filesystem images using rsync. Using the --link-dest option of rsync, you can create incremental backups from the ChunkFS-mounted image where any chunk that hasn't changed since the last backup will be a hard link to the corresponding chunk from the previous backup.

Comment: Seems to be pretty much exactly what I was writing. Funny since I actually already have pretty much the same read-only functionality but am currently working on write.  Thanks for pointing me to something that already works!

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would do this at the block level. Some solutions to this include:

- Raid 0
- DRBD ( more so for mirroring, network OK )
- ZFS ( higher level of abstraction )

From a file system perspective:

- Manually store half the file on one file system and half on the other then present that through something like a custom FUSE file system ( Think complicated custom code ).
- Most file system solutions are focused on synchronization not on data partitioning.
- Hadoop ( Data Sharding, not a traditional FS  )

Comment: First bullet point is more or less what I'm looking for if any existing solutions exist.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67995/6226

You create several container files, concatenate them as a device, format them with a file system, mount that file system and put your big file in it.

Comment: sounds like it would work well but for a large number of fragments requires many loop devices (imagine mounting several large files at a time)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you could use striping (which is the technique of segmenting logically sequential data, such as a file) witn LVM for example.

Here is some info about it from RedHat:

> 2.3.2. Striped Logical Volumes When you write data to an LVM logical volume, the file system lays the data out across the underlying
>   physical volumes. You can control the way the data is written to the
>   physical volumes by creating a striped logical volume. For large
>   sequential reads and writes, this can improve the efficiency of the
>   data I/O. Striping enhances performance by writing data to a
>   predetermined number of physical volumes in round-round fashion. With
>   striping, I/O can be done in parallel. In some situations, this can
>   result in near-linear performance gain for each additional physical
>   volume in the stripe.
>   [source](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/striped_volumes.html)

[Additional info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_striping)

Comment: Can the data be stored in files though?  I suppose if I format a number of containers and mount each...