# How do I use chunkfs?

Tags: backup, filesystems

I have the same question basically as ( [Mountable filesystem that automatically splits files](https://superuser.com/questions/700281/mountable-filesystem-that-automatically-splits-files) ) and one of the answers(https://superuser.com/a/735013/390402) suggests using ChunkFS but for the life of me I've searched everywhere online. I cannot seem to get ChunkFS working. Does anyone know how do I use it? OR does someone have a better solution?

I run Arch Linux and I'm trying to split files before they get sent to a cloud storage mounted locally usng DavFS2 (WebDav)